# Javas setter method don't change email when needed

Tags: java

i created setter in sailor class and i want to change email in main class but why my setter wont change the email when its called?

i have tried to change the setter content and implement things to crew class toString method but i cant get it to work, any ideas?

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Sailor {
   private String name;
   private String email;

   public Sailor(String name, String email) {
      this.email = email;
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return this.name;
   }
   
   public String getEmail() {
      return this.email;
   }

   public void setEmail(String email) {
      this.email = email;
   }
}
    
class Crew {
   ArrayList<Sailor> sailorList = new ArrayList<>();

   public Crew() {}

   public void addCrewMember(Sailor sailor) {
      sailorList.add(new Sailor(sailor.getName(), sailor.getEmail()));
   }

   public String toString() {
      String content = "";

      for (int i = 0; i < sailorList.size(); i++) {
         content += sailorList.get(i).getName() + " (";
         content += sailorList.get(i).getEmail() + ") \n";
      }
      return content;
   }
}
    
class ObjectsCrewProgram {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Sailor firstSailor = new Sailor("Frank", "frank@mail.com");
      Sailor secondSailor = new Sailor("Susan", "susan@mail.com");
      Sailor thirdSailor = new Sailor("John", "john@sailors.com");
      Sailor fourthSailor = new Sailor("Ann", "ann@sailors.com");       
      Crew firstCrew = new Crew();
      Crew secondCrew = new Crew();
      firstCrew.addCrewMember(firstSailor);
      firstCrew.addCrewMember(secondSailor);
      firstCrew.addCrewMember(fourthSailor);
      secondCrew.addCrewMember(thirdSailor);
      secondCrew.addCrewMember(secondSailor);
      System.out.println("=== First crew ===\n" + firstCrew); 
      System.out.println("=== Second crew ===\n" + secondCrew);
      secondSailor.setEmail("Susan@sailors.com");
      System.out.println("===Second crew ===\n" + secondCrew);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why my setter wont change the email when its called?

It does.  You're just never observing that change because your program never outputs that value.

You're outputting your *crew* values:

```
System.out.println("===Second crew ===\n" + secondCrew);
```

This uses your `.toString()` method to generate that output.  But what does a "crew" object contain?  It *doesn't* contain the "sailor" objects you provided to it.  It contains *copies* of them:

```
public void addCrewMember(Sailor sailor) {
    sailorList.add(new Sailor(sailor.getName(), sailor.getEmail()));
}
```

So your order of operations is:

1. Create a `Sailor` object.
2. Create a `Crew` object.
3. Add *a copy of* the `Sailor` to the `Crew`.
4. Modify the original `Sailor`.
5. Print the `Crew`.

Instead of creating *a copy*, just add the `Sailor` itself to the `Crew`:

```
public void addCrewMember(Sailor sailor) {
    sailorList.add(sailor);
}
```

Then any changes you make to those `Sailor` objects will be visible in that `Crew`.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating new sailors with this call:

```
public void addCrewMember(Sailor sailor) {
    sailorList.add(new Sailor(sailor.getName(), sailor.getEmail()));
}
```

So you are copying the data and not adding the original sailor. So changing the original sailor has no effect.